# Rotating a group of sprites - How to calculate origin

Tags: xna, 2d, sprites, rotation

I am rotating a group of sprites in XNA, which I developed with the help of the following example:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb194912%28v=xnagamestudio.10%29.aspx

It all works very well, however, the rotations rely on a point of origin, which it will rotate around.  The problem is that I do not know how to calculate the point of origin, so that it is exactly in the center of the sprite group.

I am able to set the point of origin to where I want it, but as soon as the sprite group changes, the origin is typically off, and it doesn't rotate from the center of the group.

My main question, is there a way to calculate the center of a group of sprites?  My original idea was to calc the boundaries (left, right, top, bottom), and place the origin the the center, but this doesn't work properly.

Comment: Your bounding box solution is conceptually correct. What do you mean by "doesn't work properly"?

Comment: I would guess that it gives too much weight to the outlying sprites, an issue which taking the mean average of the positions would reduce.

Comment: Exactly.  It looks like it is rotating off center when there are certain combination of sprites, such as a small number of sprites very far off the calculated center.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have three sprites (or if they have very specific relative positions, which almost never happens) there is a special point called the [circumcentre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle) which is at an equal distance of each sprite. However, this doesn't scale to more than 3 sprites and doesn't work if they are aligned.

The best solution would probably be to compute the **[barycentre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass) of all sprites**, which is guaranteed to remain at the same position when rotating objects around it. In its basic form it's just a matter of **averaging all X and Y coordinates**. Also, it allows you to set separate weights for each sprite, if necessary.

Here is some C# code for a list of points:

```
Point bary = Point.Zero;
foreach (Point p in list)
{
    bary.X += p.X;
    bary.Y += p.Y;
}
/* Final division by list.Count. Since we handle integers,
 * we add list.Count/2 beforehands for rounding */
bary.X = (bary.X + list.Count / 2) / list.Count;
bary.Y = (bary.Y + list.Count / 2) / list.Count;
return bary;
```